# How to get into deeper variable - Json Java (Json Simple)

Tags: java, json

I have a Json code:

```
{
  "name":"My name",
  "count_pl":{
    "araw":"19 nieruchomo\u015bci",
    "colliers":"20 nieruchomo\u015bci",
    "knightfrank":"30 nieruchomo\u015bci",
    "overall":"69 nieruchomo\u015bci"
  },

  "count_en":{
  "araw":"19 estates",
  "colliers":"20 estates",
  "knightfrank":"30 estates",
  "overall":"69 estates"
  }
}
```

and I have a java code that will read it:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");          
Log.i("Name", name);
```

as You see I can get easily to the "name" but how can I acces `count_pl->araw`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String araw = (String) ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("count_pl")).get("araw");`

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in the [javadoc](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), you cane use this :

```
String araw = jsonObject.getJSONObject("count_pl").getString("araw");
```

You should always use the specific getters when you already know what type this key return, it's prettieur than casting, and also more secure.

Comment: It's been a while since I used the library. I forgot about that method. My answer was solely based on the code provided in the question. +1

Comment: Hi. I think your code will work with JSONObject, but not SimpleJSONObject. I might be wrong (newbie). Imports are here: import org.json.JSONObject; instead of import org.json.simple.JSONObject;